# Problems parsing and interpreting soil data from the SSURGO using R soilDB

Tags: r, geology, soil

I'm using R's soilDB SSURGO library to generate a soil characteristic report (pH, soil type, drainage properties, etc.) for a given lat/long, but I can't figure out how to get the 1st and 2nd horizon data for pH, clay, sand, etc. I can get only so far and then I am stumped by the documentation. Here is my progress:

For a given a latitude or longitude, e.g. 27.891051,-82.288567:

```
library(readr)
library(aqp)
library(soilDB)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(plyr)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(sqldf)
  p <- SpatialPoints(cbind( longitude,latitude), proj4string = CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84'))
  # transform to planar coordinate system for buffering
  p.aea <- spTransform(p, CRS('+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs '))
  # create 150 meter buffer
  p.aea <- gBuffer(p.aea, width = 100)
  # transform back to WGS84 G
  p.buff <- spTransform(p.aea, CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84'))
  # convert to WKT
  p.wkt <- writeWKT(p.buff)

  q <- paste0("SELECT mukey, muname
  FROM mapunit
  WHERE mukey IN (
  SELECT * from SDA_Get_Mukey_from_intersection_with_WktWgs84('", p.wkt, "')
  )")

  res <- SDA_query(q)
```

returns `res`

```
    mukey                                             muname
1 1406998 Basinger, Holopaw, and Samsula soils, depressional
2 1407011             Zolfo fine sand, 0 to 2 percent slopes
```

Let's say we pick mukey 1407011 and look up that `cokey`:

```
q <- "SELECT *
    FROM component
    WHERE mukey = '%s'"

    # run the query
    res <- SDA_query(sprintf(q,mukey))
```

`res` returns the `mukey`s as:

```
comppct_l comppct_r comppct_h compname compkind majcompflag otherph localphase slope_l slope_r slope_h slopelenusle_l slopelenusle_r slopelenusle_h
1        80        85        90    Zolfo   Series         Yes      NA         NA       0       1       2             30             61             91
    runoff tfact wei weg   erocl earthcovkind1                     earthcovkind2 hydricon hydricrating              drainagecl elev_l elev_r elev_h
1 Very low     5 250   1 Class 1    Tree cover Intermixed conifers and hardwoods     <NA>           No Somewhat poorly drained      8     20     50
  aspectccwise aspectrep aspectcwise                                                                                   geomdesc albedodry_l albedodry_r
1            0       200         360 rises on marine terraces on coastal plains, flatwoods on marine terraces on coastal plains          NA         0.3
  albedodry_h airtempa_l airtempa_r airtempa_h map_l map_r map_h reannualprecip_l reannualprecip_r reannualprecip_h ffd_l ffd_r ffd_h nirrcapcl nirrcapscl
1          NA         20         23         25  1118  1270  1422               NA               NA               NA   350   360   365         3          w
  nirrcapunit irrcapcl irrcapscl irrcapunit cropprodindex constreeshrubgrp wndbrksuitgrp rsprod_l rsprod_r rsprod_h foragesuitgrpid wlgrain wlgrass
1          NA       NA        NA         NA            NA             1ssa            NA     3000     4000     6000              NA      NA      NA
  wlherbaceous wlshrub wlconiferous wlhardwood wlwetplant wlshallowwat wlrangeland wlopenland wlwoodland wlwetland soilslippot frostact initsub_l initsub_r
1           NA      NA           NA         NA         NA           NA          NA         NA         NA        NA          NA     None         0         0
  initsub_h totalsub_l totalsub_r totalsub_h hydgrp corcon corsteel                                         taxclname  taxorder taxsuborder taxgrtgroup
1         0          0          0          0      A   High     High Sandy, siliceous, hyperthermic Oxyaquic Alorthods Spodosols     Orthods   Alorthods
           taxsubgrp taxpartsize taxpartsizemod taxceactcl taxreaction    taxtempcl taxmoistscl taxtempregime  soiltaxedition castorieindex flecolcomnum
1 Oxyaquic Alorthods       sandy       not used   not used    not used hyperthermic    Oxyaquic  hyperthermic twelfth edition            NA            6
  flhe flphe flsoilleachpot flsoirunoffpot fltemik2use fltriumph2use indraingrp innitrateleachi misoimgmtgrp vasoimgtgrp   mukey    cokey
1   NA    NA         Medium            Low         Yes           Yes         NA              NA           NA          NA 1407011 18985410
```

This returns as `cokey` of 18985410, but I can't figure out what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use `fetchSDA_component`. Here is sample code that extracts the median physical soil properties from the top two soil horizons:

```
test = fetchSDA_component(WHERE = paste0("mukey=",mukey),duplicates = FALSE, childs = TRUE, rmHzErrors = FALSE)
    test=test[1:2]
    awc=as.double(summary(test$awc_r)['Median'])
    pH=as.double(summary(test$ph1to1h2o_r)['Median'])
    sand=as.double(summary(test$sandtotal_r)['Median'])
    clay=as.double(summary(test$claytotal_r)['Median'])
    organic=as.double(summary(test$om_r)['Median'])
    drainage=as.character(test[1]$drainagecl)
    taxpartsize=as.character(test[1]$taxceactcl)
```